# SwiftUI NavigationStack pass vars through enum?

Tags: swiftui

Can I pass a variable through my Route enum in SwiftUI for my NavigationStack? In this example I am attempting to pass `input: String` through the Route enum into my views `@State var output: String`.

```
@available(iOS 16.0, *)
enum Route: Hashable {
    case first(input: String)
    @ViewBuilder
    func view(_ path: Binding<NavigationPath>) -> some View{
        switch self {
        //ERROR HERE: cannot find input var to pass to view
        case .first: AView1(output: input)
        }
    }
}

@available(iOS 16.0, *)
struct AView1: View {
    @State var output: String
    @State var path: NavigationPath = .init()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path){
            VStack{
                Text(output)
                NavigationLink(value: Route.first(input: "Hello"), label: {Text("Click")})
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Route.self){ route in
                route.view($path)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea to put the `switch` in a `@ViewBuilder` inside the `enum`, I usually always do it in `navigationDestination` which is already a view builder.

Comment: @malhal Thanks, I'm hoping it'll make my code cleaner and more reusable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try changing

```
 case .first: AView1(output: input)
```

to

```
 case .first(let input): AView1(output: input)
```